# How do I install BCM4312 wireless drivers?

Tags: wireless, kernel, drivers, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

completely new to Ubuntu. How do I add Wireless driver for my laptop? I am running a Dell XPS M1330. Right now its acts as if I dont have a Wi-Fi card.

:~$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HEM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA AHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G86 [GeForce 8400M GS] (rev a1)
03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
03:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
03:01.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
03:01.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 12)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have **BCM4312** wireless card too.

What I needed to do:

1. Go to: *System->Administrator->Additional Drivers(Hardware drivers)*
2. Then click to *Broadcom STA wireless driver* and enable it.
3. Restart

To me it's the easiest way.

Comment: Picked.... :) How do we search wireless networks?

Comment: Switch wireless on and the wait. Available wireless networks are coming under NetworkManager Applet (just click). Choose what you need.

Answer (score 7):

The STA driver in 11.04 doesn't work due to a kernel issue. You will have to install the B43xx firmware. Just install firmware-b43-installer from the Software Center or Synaptic.

You can also do it from the command line: `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

Answer (score 7):

Well I have Broadcom 4312 wifi and installed the sta  driver using the terminal

Click the dash, type 'terminal'and  issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

It worked a treat, first time on a new install of 11.04

Hope that helps

[image: This is what it looks like to use]

Answer (score 2):

I followed the **Medieval**'s [steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/12109/74307), but (for me) it was incomplete.

Then I had to go to **System Settings** → **Additional Drivers** → then **Activate** the wireless card.

Then up in the menu desktop, I clicked **Enable Wireless**.

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) is the guide of all you will know about setup and configure a broadcom 43xx in ubuntu. include install, configuration and problem

you need to install STA drivers

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for ndiswrapper and Windows drivers, because the Linux driver already exists,

- if you see no broadcom wireless device name, uninstall driver,
  restart computer, install driver and restart again until "firmware
  missing" message appears with wifi device name under wireless icon
  after clicking on it (gnome).
- If you haven't it, you must install a synaptic package manager from
  Ubuntu software center
- search "bcm" inside synaptic package manager
- mark for installation "b43-fwcutter", "firmware-b43-installer" or
  "firmware-b43-lpphy-installer"(if you have a broadcom lpphy driver),
  "firmware-b43legacy-installer" and apply, no restart needed. Your
  Wi-Fi led turns on immediately.