# Can't get wireless card to be recognized - Dell D630 - Broadcom BCM4311

Tags: 11.04, drivers, dell, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install BCM4312 wireless drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11993/how-do-i-install-bcm4312-wireless-drivers)

Below are the results for `sudo lshw -c network` command.  I believe "UNCLAIMED" refers to missing drivers.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f1ffc000-f1ffffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1c:23:2f:06:45
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.116 firmware=5755m-v3.29 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:f1ef0000-f1efffff
```

Answer (score 0):

The STA driver in 11.04 doesn't work due to a kernel issue.  You will have to install the B43xx firmware.  Just install firmware-b43-installer from the software center or synaptic.

You can also do it from the command line.

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

Comment: have tried this and few others.  I still have no wireless:


sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firmware-b43-installer is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libzlcore
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
baskint@leibniz:~$

Comment: package is there, but interface is still "UNCLAIMED"??