# How do you solve the problem of a laptop's inability to detect wireless networks?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, dell, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install BCM4312 wireless drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11993/how-do-i-install-bcm4312-wireless-drivers)

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.04 to dual-boot with the Windows XP in my Dell™ Inspiron E1505 laptop. Unfortunately, I can only connect to our wireless network while in Windows. In Ubuntu, I can't go online unless I physically connect it to our cable modem.

I am still a beginner, here is what I was able to get from searching online. Here is my hardware:

```
kalayaan001@Kalayaan-MM061:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7 Family) SATA IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon Mobility X1400
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
03:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 19)
03:01.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 0a)
03:01.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 05)
0b:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
```

I also checked the status of Network Manager:

```
kalayaan001@Kalayaan-MM061:~$ nm-applet
An instance of nm-applet is already running.

** (nm-applet:1727): WARNING **: <WARN>  constructor(): Couldn't initialize the D-Bus manager.
```

How can we initialize the D-Bus manager?

```
kalayaan001@Kalayaan-MM061:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            b44
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:19:B9:85:01:CA

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           10 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

It seems that all it can detect are the devices of wired Internet. How can we make it recognize the devices for wireless?

I then checked for blocks, but found none.

```
kalayaan001@Kalayaan-MM061:~$ rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So, I thought it to be a driver problem and, surely enough, I found in "Additional Drivers" that it was lacking in a Broadcom® STA wireless driver. Unfortunately, getting the driver didn't fix it, either. It still cannot detect anything.

How is this fixed?

*」ר_ Please, assist! _ΓL*

Thank you for your time.

Take care,
Kalayaan 001

---

---

### Response to sagarchalise:

I installed all 4 entries under the keyword "bcm4311": firmware-b43-installer, bcmwl-kernel-source, broadcom-sta-common, and broadcom-sta-source. (There is even b43-fwcutter, though that appears for the broader keywork "bcm".) The problems is still there.

Additional Drivers reports: "This driver is activated and currently in use."

Here is ifconfig:

```
kalayaan001@Kalayaan-MM061:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:b9:85:01:ca  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:720 (720.0 B)  TX bytes:720 (720.0 B)
```

Here is iwconfig:

```
kalayaan001@Kalayaan-MM061:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

How can I get these extensions?

The results of 2 codes seem to have changed in the process:

1) nm-tool

```
kalayaan001@Kalayaan-MM061:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool
```

Everything after "Tool" is gone.

2) sudo lshw -C network
Before:

```
kalayaan001@Kalayaan-MM061:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for kalayaan001: 
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:efcfc000-efcfffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:19:b9:85:01:ca
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 duplex=half latency=64 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff
```

After:

```
kalayaan001@Kalayaan-MM061:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for kalayaan001: 
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:efcfc000-efcfffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:19:b9:85:01:ca
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 duplex=half latency=64 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff
```

After:

```
kalayaan001@Kalayaan-MM061:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for kalayaan001:
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:efcfc000-efcfffff
   *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=64
       resources: memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff
```

In Ubuntu code, what does"UNCLAIMED" mean?

I tried the code suggested in the website. Unfortunately, there was no effect. I will try again in the morning (It's past bedtime in my timezone. So, I'm just about to retire to bed.)

Any more proposals?

Thanks again for your time. Your reply is most appreciated.

Take care,

Kalayaan 001

Answer (score 1):

Basically check on additional driver section if it is in use or not.

[image]

Try `ifconfig` or `iwconfig` to see if you have a wireless interface or not. Sometimes you may need to install an alternative broadcom driver if the additional drivers recommendation fails. Try different broadcom option from `Synaptic Package Manager` with search keyword `bcm4311`. Or follow more instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx).

Comment: I just got back to XP after trying it on Ubuntu. I'll post the results on the main question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had to re-space the codes. Thanks again!