# How to set master mode on BCM4312 to share internet from 3G USB modem

Tags: wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install BCM4312 wireless drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11993/how-do-i-install-bcm4312-wireless-drivers)

[WifiDocs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode) said:

> Broadcom cards support master mode using the reverse-engineered kernel
>   driver. You need to enable (or make as a module) the Softmac wireless
>   extensions and BCM43xx wireless driver

Where can I download that driver and enable it?

Comment: Can you explain why this is a different question from this one?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/11993/how-do-i-install-bcm4312-wireless-drivers

Comment: dupe -  vote to close