# how to setup wifi

Tags: wireless

The only OS I have used has been windows but I wanted to try lubuntu on a netbook. I'm booting from a flash drive to try it out first. How do I connect the wifi. Remember I'm new to this so I not sure how the OS even works completely aka sudo command.

Comment: Can you tell us the brand and model of your netbook?  If your wireless card is supported, you should be able to just click on the wifi icon on the top panel near the clock to see and connect to nearby networks.  It looks like this: http://www.muktware.com/wp-content/uploads/Lubuntu-wifi.jpg  If you don't see it, you may have to install some drivers.

Comment: It a hp mini 1030nr. The wifi card is a bmc4312. There is is no wifi icon, it will connect to a ethernet.

Comment: Sorry I meant bcm4312

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are two solutions given in a previous thread about getting a bcm4312 adapter working, and they seem fairly simple:

> I have BCM4312 wireless card too.
>
> What I needed to do:
>
> Go to: System->Administrator->Additional Drivers(Hardware drivers)
>   *(In Lubuntu, the Additional Drivers menu should be under System Tools.)*
>   Then click to Broadcom STA wireless driver and enable it.
>
> Restart
>
> To me it's the easiest way.

And here's the second:

> You will have to install the B43xx firmware. Just install
>   firmware-b43-installer from the Software Center or Synaptic.
>
> You can also do it from the command line: `sudo apt-get install
>   firmware-b43-installer`

Source: [How do I install BCM4312 wireless drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11993/how-do-i-install-bcm4312-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Ok it recognizes the wireless card now, but other than picking up a device mac address that's it. Not sure how to go about getting ssid, bssid, or any of the other things it is asking about. I thought it would automatically connect and ask for my I.D. name and password.

Comment: @Chuck how are you trying to connect?  Do you see the wifi symbol in the top panel now?